# Contadicts Radon-Nikodym Patrick Billingsley

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, self-learning, radon-nikodym

I am self-studying Probability Theory.
I am unable to solve the below problem

( Probability and Measure, 3e by Patrick Billingsley, Exercise 32.5

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Radon-Nikodym theorem requires $\sigma$-finite measures. Is it the case of $\mu$?

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show how would you prove it formally, I would really appreciate it